# Simple generator seems to be broken

Tags: javascript, generator, yield

I have written a simple generator:

```
function geni()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        yield i;
    }
}
```

And I get the error as below:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
>   [Break On This Error]
>
> `yield i;`

Browser: Firefox 19.0.2
OS: Windows 7.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did not know about this feature of JavaScript, that's cool :)

Comment: Yeah, this is my first time trying it out. It's a nice bit of syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you including this in your head tags?

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"></script>
```

Version 1.7 is required for `yield.`

Comment: That's the problem! Thanks a lot. I'll accept in 12 minutes, apparently.